# How to search a file for lines that contain a particular string but not a particular string?

Tags: file, unix

I have a file in which I want to output all the lines containing a particular phrase but not another phrase to a different file. For example here is a sample file:

qwert **catsanddogs** werwer
sdfg **catsandlions** sdfggf
dfhgsdg **catsandtigers** dhjtjye
tqvtw erytwy weyyq
........

So I want to redirect all the lines which have **cats** but not the lines which have **catsanddogs** into another file.

Can anyone explain how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` is a tool that can filter inputs. Basically you can describe what you want to catch (with regexp — a regexp describes a set of words) and decide if you want to include or exclude a line (grep works on lines of text) on the output.

`grep -v` could be your friend :

```
cat myfile | grep cats | grep -v catsandlions > resultfile
```

You first filter each line that contains `cats` and then from this exclude all that contains `catsandlions`.

You can also make the converse : exclude `catandlions` first and the include `cats`.